# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'find')"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to push an object to an array using vuex but i'm getting this error. I don't know why in Edge works great, but in Chrome and Opera it doesn't.

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'find')"*

Vuex store:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    shoppingCartItems: [], 
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_ITEM(state, payload) {
      if (state.shoppingCartItems.find(item => item.type === 'custom-item')) {
        state.shoppingCartItems.push(payload)
      } else if (state.shoppingCartItems.find(item => item.name === payload.name)) {
        const index = state.shoppingCartItems.findIndex(item => item.name === payload.name)
        const value = payload.quantity
        state.shoppingCartItems[index].quantity += value
      } else {
        state.shoppingCartItems.push(payload)
      }
    },
  }
}
```

In SET_ITEM I'm checking if the payload is an item that already is in the array so instead of adding again, it sums 1 to this specific item. And again, in Edge it's working perfectly, but in Chrome everything seems to be broken.

Example of payload that SET_ITEM is receiving:

```
payload = {
dimensions: "30x10cm"
extraLine: 2
extraQuote: "no"
frases: [__ob__: Observer]
image: ""
name: "custom-item"
namesQuantity: 1
names: [{…}, __ob__: Observer]
price: 180
quantity: 1
type: "custom-item"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried. I tried to clean cache, cookies and open in private tab

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any problems in the code you've shown. Enable [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html) to make sure you're not altering state outside of a mutation. You can also use the [Vue Devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) browser extension to get a better overview of your store at runtime.

Comment: Strict mode didn't work. But I'm not sure its usage to be honest. I tried to use Vue Devtools but I couldn't find what is causing the errors. It's really wierd, in Edge everything works perfectly.

Comment: I'm going to upload a print screen of the errors when I set strict mode to true when I'm creating the vuex store

Comment: If you're getting errors reported with strict mode on, then you need to fix those errors. My guess is you're setting `state.shoppingCartItems` to `null` somewhere unexpected

Comment: You were right! I found out that when I'm creating Vue.app I'm setting shoppingCartItems to the last shoppingCartItems that I had in localStorage. So when I opened a clean browser, it was set to null. I just didn't understand why it works on Edge but no  on Chrome.  Well... thanks! You guided me to look to the right path. :)

Comment: Always have strict mode enabled for development